# Configuring Drupal for Upstream Deployment

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to help a co-worker configure a Drupal site so that we can deploy the same site upstream without making database changes. We're having trouble with file paths. Here's what I have:

1. A Nginx webroot pointing to the root of my Drupal 6 (in this case) install (`/opt/frameworks/drupal-6`).
2. The content for this site is in `/opt/www/my-site`.
3. A symlink exists in `/opt/frameworks/drupal-6/sites`: `dev-my-site -> /opt/www/dev-my-site`

Because of some sharing that's going on, there are multiple versions of `my-site` on the box, so they have to have different symlink names. Right now, the "file system path" is set to `sites/dev-my-site/files` which breaks when moved upstream.

Is there a way that I can set a configuration variable to override the database setting? Or is there a better way to configure my webroot and sites? I don't know much about Drupal, but I'd like to build this out so that deployments are as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bunch of trial and error by 2 inexperienced Drupal folks has led to a possible solution. It looks like setting the `$conf['file_system_directory']` in `settings.php` does exactly what we need. Each site on each box will have it's own settings file that isn't touched by deployments, so we might be all good.

If there's a better way or if there are unintended side effects to this particular way, I'd love to hear answers from more experienced Drupal admins.